# correlate multiple values using json extractor

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

i am new to performance testing, currently working on one scenario where we need to correlate id, field type & allowed_otypes

for allowed_types we need to pick the first value of the payload, for example from the below mentioned json it would be user form the first payload & profile from the second payload

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "field_type": "DISPLAY_SET",
        "tooltip_text": null,
        "name_plural": "Approvers",
        "name_singular": "Approver",
        "backref_name": null,
        "backref_tooltip_text": null,
        "allow_multiple": true,
        "allowed_otypes": [
            "user",
            "groupprofile",
            "groupprofile"
        ],
        "options": null,
        "builtin_name": "approver",
        "can_view": null,
        "can_edit": null,
        "flavor": "DEFAULT",
        "tag_ds_id": null,
        "tag_schema_name": null
    },
    {
        "id": 10022,
        "field_type": "DATA_SET",
        "tooltip_text": "Approvers",
        "name_plural": "Approvers",
        "name_singular": "Approvers",
        "backref_name": "Approvers",
        "backref_tooltip_text": "Approvers",
        "allow_multiple": true,
        "allowed_otypes": [
            "profile",
            "groupprofile",
            "groupprofile"
        ],
        "options": null,
        "builtin_name": null,
        "can_view": null,
        "can_edit": null,
        "flavor": "DEFAULT",
        "tag_ds_id": null,
        "tag_schema_name": null
    }
]
```

all of the these three variables are interlinked to each other, how to extract all three variables with one expression, please help me

Answer (score 1):

To correlate the id, field_type, and allowed_types from the provided JSON, you can use a combination of techniques such as filtering, mapping, and iterating over the JSON data.

```
 const extractedData = jsonData.map(item => ({
    id: item.id,
    field_type: item.field_type,
    allowed_types: item.allowed_otypes
}));


console.log(extractedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 1st item from `allowed_otypes` [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) for all "payloads" you can do it using the following [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression:

```
$..allowed_otypes[0]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

Comment: sorry for not framing question correctly, i need to pick id, field type & allowed_otypes in one json expression, if i do individually then then script is getting failed due to miss match in the passing of wrong values

Comment: ok, in this case you can add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request and use the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) there: `vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).collect { item -> [id: item.id, field_type: item.field_type, allowed_otypes: [item.allowed_otypes[0]]] }).toPrettyString())`. You will be able to refer generated payload as `${payload}` where required.